# Proof that $\operatorname{Ext}^n_{kG}(M,N) = \operatorname{Hom}(\Omega^nM, N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $k$ be a field of modular characteristic. Write $\mathsf{St}_k(G)$ for the stable module category of $G$. It is the triangulated category obtained from $\mathsf{Mod}_k(G)$ by quotienting out the projectives. Its endofunctor $\Omega$ is obtained by taking the kernel of a projective envelope.

It is a fact that
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{St}(G)}(\Omega^n M , N) \cong \operatorname{Ext}^n_{kG}(M,N).$$
Despite being well-known and basic, the literature on the topic is so poor that I haven't been able to find a reference or proof. This brings me to the

**Question:** Does anyone know a reference or proof of this fact?

In fact, I said the literature is poor, but I'd even go as far as saying that it is nonexistent. Because of this let me also ask the

**Bonus question:** Does anyone know any reference which introduces the stable module category?

Comment: There's loads of literature introducing those things! For example, Carlson's ETH notes "Modules and group algebras", Benson's "Representations and cohomology".

Comment: @MatthewTowers Hmm. I was aware that Benson's book briefly mentions the existence of the category though I thought he gave it no further attention. I'll take a look at the notes of Carlson you mention.

Comment: Ah, found it! Thm. 5.1 of Carlson's notes. Thanks for pointing me to that reference. In fact, it answers the bonus question too!

Comment: One should be wary of blaming the literature for being poor: it usually is richer than you expect it to be! ;)

Comment: I am fairly certain these results are in Benson, but I am separated from my copy by the lockdown.